# Approaching "How much would you pay to play this game"-type game of chance questions

Tags: probability, game-theory

It appears that a somewhat common interview question for quantitative jobs involves asking the interviewee to submit a maximum price he would be willing to pay to play a game of chance. This question is posed as an auction (sometimes sealed-bid) against other unknown players such that you will minimise your expected payoff.

These questions usually describe a game where the expected value and standard deviation are easy to determine, rather the intent is for the recipient to determine a satisfactory expected payoff. For the purposes of this question, ignore the recipient's value of time.

Here is a simple example of such a question:

> A fair coin is tossed four times. If the coin comes up heads all four times the player wins $16, otherwise the game is over. The game is played only once. What is the maximum price you would pay to play this game?

In this case, the expected value of the game seems reasonably clear:

$$E[X] = \frac{1}{2^4} * \$16 = \$1.$$

But the game is played only once, and to pay $1 would be to accept zero expected payoff. So how might one approach determining their expected payoff? As I understand it, this is a question of risk appetites and might not have one clear approach. By risk I refer to the standard deviation of returns.

*Note: While I see there have been many posts about these sorts of questions, it seems they often focus on calculating expected value and variance, or the post inadequately parameterises the question. I am hoping there might be a nice game-theory approach to answering these questions, where the focus is not on expected value but risk of playing the game.*

Comment: I will pay 0 dollar to play, but if I'm the dealer I won't accept any bid below 16.  So I never lose any money over silly games like this (or even better, getting paid to play). /s

Comment: Define what you mean by "risk".  Common folk use it for downside risk, which is what my previous comment try to address, but quantitative jobs probably expect `risk = volatility = standard deviation` type which is why you see the expected value and variance as "sufficient" answer.

Comment: @user10354138 I'll try and clarify this in the question, thanks. Yes, I did mean risk as standard deviation but the question is how that can be built into one's price. Why would you pay $0 to play? The dealer accepts the best bid - it is an auction.

Comment: With the downside risk version, the payoff is $-\infty$ for any loss, so not play at all or play with OPM (other people's money), no?

Comment: To answer to the query, you must provide more info, re **quantifying** the extent that you are either risk-seeking or risk-averse.  For example, if you are risk-averse, then winning $\$16$ might be only 5 times as *significant* as losing $\$1$.  In such a case, I would pay $\$(5/16)$.  For more complicated problems, where you may (in effect) have partial wins/losses, then (**yes**), standard deviation becomes relevant.  For the given query, with no info given, I must **blindly assume** that you are risk-neutral, which makes the max price $\$1$.

Comment: Relevant Wikipedia article: [Risk aversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_aversion)